# Replace ÅÄÖ (both capital and lowercase) with javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm trying to replace Å, Ä and Ö in a user input (a column name) variable. This variable need ex. *x00e5* for "å" etc for using retrieving columns (by internalName) from SharePoint, therefore I need the correct format.

I'm checking if the input value has any of Å, Ä and Ö (both capital and lower):

```
switch (inputValue) {
 case inputValue.indexOf('å') > -1:
   inputValue = inputValue.replace(/å/g, '_x00e5_');
   break;
 case inputValue.indexOf('Å') > -1:
   inputValue = inputValue.replace(/Å/g, '_x00c5_');
   break;
 case inputValue.indexOf('ä') > -1:
   inputValue = inputValue.replace(/ä/g, '_x00e4_');
   break;
 case inputValue.indexOf('Ä') > -1:
   inputValue = inputValue.replace(/Ä/g, '_x00c4_');
   break;
 case inputValue.indexOf('ö') > -1:
   inputValue = inputValue.replace(/ö/g, '_x00e6_');
   break;
 case inputValue.indexOf('Ö') > -1:
   inputValue = inputValue.replace(/Ö/g, '_x00c6_');
   break;
 default:
   break;
}
```

Even if one case condition is true, it never enters the case.

This cannot be the simplest/best solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no harm in calling `replace()` if the target substring is not present.  So no `switch` is needed:

```
inputValue = inputValue
  .replace(/å/g, '_x00e5_')
  .replace(/Å/g, '_x00c5_')
  .replace(/ä/g, '_x00e4_')
  .replace(/Ä/g, '_x00c4_')
  .replace(/ö/g, '_x00e6_')
  .replace(/Ö/g, '_x00c6_');
```